# How can I improve upon this Insertion Sort?

Tags: c#, loops, sorting, for-loop, arraylist

I feel as if this is too inefficient for an insertion sort. Most implementations  that I've seen will have a while loop in place of my second for loop. Along with that as well is that those while loops will terminate once j in my code, or the equivalent of that,  is equal to zero or once my if statement, found in the for loop of my code, is executed. The problem is that whenever I've tried to implement code like that my insertion sort hasn't worked properly.

getVisitCount just returns an integer of the class Webpage. AL is an ArrayList.

```
public void IS()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorting ArrayList.");
        for (int i = 1; i < AL.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            {
                Webpage EntryJ = (Webpage)AL[j];
                Webpage EntryBefore = (Webpage)AL[j - 1];

                if (EntryBefore.getVisitCount() < EntryJ.getVisitCount())
                {
                    Webpage temp = EntryBefore;
                    AL[j - 1] = AL[j];
                    AL[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Some punctuation in your question would be nice. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using ArrayList when you can use a [List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1)? What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: If you think Insertion sort is inefficient, I couldn't agree more, you can try another sorting algorithm like "Quick Sort" or "Merge Sort" for faster output. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @VincentElbertBudiman - For a small number of elements, InsertionSort can be even faster than other algorithms. In fact there are algorithms like [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) which are optimized so they switch to InsertionSort for sorting small parts of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort an array list you can cast it to your specific type and then transform it to list. With list you can simply invoke LINQ OrderBy to get the list ordered:

```
public class Webpage
{
    public int getVisitCount()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Second * 2;
    }

    public static List<Webpage> Sort(ArrayList AL)
    {
        var list = AL.Cast<Webpage>().ToList();
        var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.getVisitCount());

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Linq sorting is not stable (equal elements do not always keep their original order), so this may or may not meet the OPs intention.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what your code is doing :

```
            int[] AL = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
            for (int i = 1; i < AL.Count(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    if (AL[j-1] < AL[j])
                    {
                        int temp = AL[j -1];
                        AL[j - 1] = AL[j];
                        AL[j] = temp;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("i = '{0}', j = '{1}', array = '{2}'", i.ToString(), j.ToString(),string.Join(",", AL.Select(x => x.ToString())));
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]